# Want to export environment variable from startup script to other shells

Tags: shell, environment-variables, busybox

I'm working on an embedded system using Busybox as the shell.  My startup script rcS exports a number of variables:

```
UBOOT_ENV="gatewayip netmask netdev ipaddr ethaddr eth1addr hostname nfsaddr"
for i in $UBOOT_ENV; do
        if [ -n "$i" ] ; then
                export `fw_printenv $i`
        fi
done
```

which are then available to scripts called from this script as I'd expect.  What I want however is for these environment variables to be set in the environment for which some web server scripts are called.  This is currently not the case.  How do I make an environment variable available to any shell script called?

TY,
Fred

ps : my busybox is BusyBox v1.11.2 (2012-02-26 12:08:09 PST) built-in shell (msh)

Comment: Web servers tend to be fussy about which, if any, environment variables they pay any attention to.  You may need to add a `PassEnv` directive to your `httpd.conf` if your web server is Apache.

Answer (score 2):

Environment variables are only inherited by child processes of your script (and their child processes); you can't push them up to a parent process.

What you can do is write the variables to a file (as a shell script) which you can then include from wherever you like. Put `source filename` in `/etc/.profile` and it will probably do what you want.